# Populate ASP DataGrid With Fields With Spaces

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, webforms

I have a SQL Server table that has fields with spaces in it.  I am attempting to populate an asp datagrid with this information, but on the Bind() event I keep getting an error of

> Additional information: A field or property with the name '[Field With Space]' was not found on the selected data source.

I know the field is properly named as if I run it in SSMS it executes properly.  Below is my HTML and my C# - what is set-up incorrectly?

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LSTMain"].ConnectionString))
{
    cn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Field With Space] FROM [Inventory Log] order by ID ASC", cn);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    GridView1.DataSource = dr;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    cn.Close();
}


<div id="dgv">
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="Grid" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="[Field With Space]" HeaderText="SQL Field With Spaces" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: So probably `DataField` should not contain spaces.

Comment: @S.Akbari - so i need to rename the fields with spaces in my SQL Table?

Comment: @S.Akbari - removing the spaces from the SQL Server Table field names seems to remedy.  Just a nuisance this is the only way to achieve such.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the datareader dr.GetString(0)